# Executing async tasks

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency

I need help to better understanding how works concurrency in Swift.

I have the code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("A")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print("B")
        }
        print("C")
    }
    print("D")
}
```

Result: **D A C B**

I guess "D" was first only for one reason, executing of the first Dispatch block consist of 2 steps:

1. Put the task in queue
2. Execute task

And it takes more time than executing **print("D")**. Is that right?

When I experimented with concurrency queues, in one of the cases I got the next result: **A D C B**.

Why it happened?

Concurrency queue code:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        print("A")
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
            print("B")
        }
        print("C")
    }
    print("D")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that there can be many global queues with the same QoS, but there will always be only one main queue.

Your first example is predictable - it will always behave the same, because you're always dispatching tasks to the same queue - main. Tasks submitted with `async` will be performed asynchronously (which means `async` function will return immediately) but a new task will not start execution until a currently executed task finishes. Here's a simplified model of what happens:

```
Task 1:
    Submit task 2
    Print "D"

Task 2:
    Print "A"
    Submit task 3
    Print "C"

Task 3:
    Print "B"
```

`Task 1` consists of submitting `Task 2` and printing stuff. `Task 1` is running on main queue, and `Task 2` is added to the same queue. This means `Task 2` cannot start until currently running task - `Task 1` - finishes execution.

Seconf example is a little different. Each time you call `DispatchQueue.global`, you are guaranteed to get a queue with a specific QoS, but it will not necessarily be the same queue. It would seem that the queue you dispatched `print("A")` to didn't have any other tasks pending and was able to execute its work immediately, before `async` method returned.

Using previously provided model - if `Task 2` is added to a different queue than `Task 1` is running on, then it will not need to wait for `Task 1` to finish execution. But again, in this case it all depends on what queue you get each time you call `DispatchQueue.global` and that is not guaranteed

Comment: So why 'print("D")' appear first? It's all async.